# Como indicar a una consulta PreparedStatement que no voy a utilizar uno de los argumentos como filtrado

Tags: java, mysql, sql

me gustaría saber si es posible, en un momento dado, no pasar uno de los parámetros a una consulta preparada y que no se tenga en cuente a la hora del filtrado de la consulta.

Actualmente tengo este código:

```
    PreparedStatement miStatement = miConexion.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ALUMNOS WHERE CURSO=? AND TURNO=?");
```

Y mediante el método setString paso por parametros las opciones de filtrado:

```
    miStatement.SetString(1,"PRIMERO");
    miStatement.SetString(2,"TARDE");
```

Es posible "anular" el primer setString para que no lo tenga en cuenta en el filtrado y así me seleccione todos los alumnos del turno de TARDE independientemente del curso?

Answer (score 1):

Sobrecargas el método que envia los parametros al PS y usas lógica para declarar cual versión vas a utilizar.

ej

```
if(alumnosTextBox.getText.equals(""))
   buscarAlumnos(miParametro1)
else
   buscarAlumnos(miParametro1, miParametro2)
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Si, al final lo he hecho así. Aunque la idea era ver la posibilidad de utilizar la misma consulta preparada para cualquier combinación.

Comment: Es que el problema aquí no es la consulta preparada, sino la consulta como tal. Digamos que en efecto puedes hacer que la CP ignore el primer parámetro... OK, ahora terminas con un `WHERE` que dice "Curso = and turno=?". No es SQL válido. Le estás pasando un string que representa la consulta, y la CP tiene una lógica interna que le permite reemplazar cada ? Por un parámetro correspondiente. Pero si le dices "ignora X parámetro", para que funcione no tendría que nada más decir que el parámetro no vale nada, sino que tendría que remover el criterio del todo, cambiando totalmente la consulta.